# Create string from not empty field values

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I'm using the following functions to check if each part of an address contains a value, either a full address exists address city state zip or only a city and state. What is a clean method to write this function. I was thinking there must be a way to insert each variable in to an array and loop over each array member checking if it contains a value to create the string.

```
$location_name = get_field('location_name');
$address = get_field('address');
$city = get_field('city');
$state = get_field('state');
$zipcode = get_field('zipcode');

if($location_name){
    $location = $location_name;
}
if($address){
    $location .= $address.', ';
}
if($city){
    $location .= $city;
}
if($state){
    $location .= ', '.$state;
}
if($zipcode){
    $location .= $zipcode;
}
```

Comment: `$location = implode(', ', array_filter(array(get_field('location_name'), get_field('address'), get_field('city'), get_field('state'), get_field('zipcode')));`

Comment: @MarkBaker put this as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$location = implode(
    ', ', 
    array_filter(
        array(
            get_field('location_name'), 
            get_field('address'), 
            get_field('city'), 
            get_field('state'), 
            get_field('zipcode')
        )
    )
);
```